# Javascript: If scrolled to a specific destination fade out, if scrolled back up again, fade back in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fade out something if the user scrolled past 500px. This works fine! But if I want to fade it back in if the user scrolls back up it doesn't work anymore.
Whats am I missing?

```js
var $document = $(document),
    $element = $('#some-element'),
    className = 'hasScrolled';

$document.scroll(function() {
  if ($document.scrollTop() >= 500) {
    $( "#thePlayer,#playlist").animate({
    opacity: 0,
  }, 2000 );
    $element.addClass(className);
  } else {
    $element.removeClass(className);
    $( "#thePlayer,#playlist").animate({
    opacity: 1,
  }, 2000 );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it with using fadeIn and fadeOut!

Sorry!

```js
var $document = $(document),
    $element = $('#some-element'),
    className = 'hasScrolled';

$document.scroll(function() {
  if ($document.scrollTop() >= 500) {
    $( "#thePlayer,#playlist").fadeOut("slow");
    $element.addClass(className);
  } else {
    $element.removeClass(className);
    $( "#thePlayer,#playlist").fadeIn("slow");
  }
});
```